# VIM + netrw: accessing a machine behind a gateway

Tags: networking, ssh, vim

I'd like to setup a vim session to edit some files on a machine behind an ssh gateway.  Is this possible?

To access the files via the command line, I have to do:

```
mycomputer$ ssh gateway
gateway$ ssh othermachine
othermachine$ vim file
```

The gateway machine does not allow normal ssh forwarding:

```
> nc
rbash: nc: command not found
> /usr/bin/nc   
rbash: /usr/bin/nc: restricted: cannot specify `/' in command names
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469645/using-vim-to-remotely-edit-a-file-on-serverb-only-accessible-from-servera); it does require `nc` on the gateway, though.

Answer (score 1):

Netrw has a "g:netrw_scp_cmd" variable; I wonder if there's something you could set it to that would use the gateway; something like "ssh gateway 'scp -q'".  I don't have a gateway setup to test this idea; you'll have to play with it.